# File uploading error in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I am trying to upload an image in codeigniter.

here is my view file code.

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('pages/data_submitted') ?>" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Image: <input type="file" name="image"/>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

and this is my controller code.

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller 
{ 
 public function data_submitted(){
 $config['upload_path']   =   "img/";
$this->load->library('upload',$config);
$this->upload->do_upload();
$finfo=$this->upload->data();
$data = $this->upload->display_errors();

$this->load->model('user_model');
$this->user_model->insert_item($data);
}
}
```

and here is my model code

```
<?php
class User_model extends CI_Model {
function __construct(){
    /* Call the Model constructor */
    parent::__construct();
}


public function insert_item($item){

    print_r($item);
}
}
?>
```

What is wrong with this code...
Here I passed $data just to check whether any error occur or not. 
And it is showing "You did not select a file to upload.' even I select a file.
please help me.

Comment: Don't use "get" requests, the maximum "get" request for web browsers is 8K. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request

Comment: check this http://only4ututorials.blogspot.in/2015/06/how-to-upload-image-in-codeigniter.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer this code. this will surely work for you

```
public function uploadImage() {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));  
        $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/images/b2bcategory';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';
        $config['max_width'] = '2024';
        $config['max_height'] = '1768';
        $config['width'] = 75;
        $config['height'] = 50;
        if (isset($_FILES['catimage']['name'])) {
            $filename = "-" . $_FILES['catimage']['name'];
            $config['file_name'] = substr(md5(time()), 0, 28) . $filename;
        }
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $field_name = "catimage";
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ($this->input->post('selsub')) {
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('catimage')) {
                //no file uploaded or failed upload
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            } else {
                $dat = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $this->resize($dat['upload_data']['full_path'],           $dat['upload_data']['file_name']);
            }
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            if (empty($dat['upload_data']['file_name'])) {
                $catimage = '';
            } else {
                $catimage = $dat['upload_data']['file_name'];
            }
            $data = array(            
                'ctg_image' => $catimage,
                'ctg_dated' => time()
            );
            $this->b2bcategory_model->form_insert($data);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
<button>Submit</button>
```

to this :

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
```

---

**In Controller**

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller 
{ 
    public function data_submitted(){

        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $config['upload_path']   =   "./img/";
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; # Changed 

        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $data = $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
        else{
            $finfo = $this->upload->data();
            $this->load->model('user_model');
            $this->user_model->insert_item($finfo);
        }

        # Load the view on here

    }
}
```

Comment: tried ur code but didn't work .. ty for ur valuable comment

Comment: same error that You didn't select a file. And how to save the path of file in DB, IN CI

Comment: did you add this `if(!$this->upload->do_upload('image'))`

Comment: $finfo returns array.so to get name of file u need to change it

Comment: yes i used if(!$this->upload->do_upload('image')) but no idea

Answer (score 2):

You have to mention the field name in the do_upload method.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="field_name"/>
</form>

<?php
 $this->upload->do_upload('field_name');
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

**view page**

```
<?php echo echo form_open_multipart(base_url('Pages/data_submitted'),['name' => 'form', 'id' => 'form']);

  //or <form action="<?php echo base_url('Pages/data_submitted') ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   Image: <input type="file" name="image"/>
   <button id="button" name="button">Submit</button>

</form>
```

**controller**

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller 
{ 
    public function data_submitted(){

        $config['upload_path'] = getcwd().'/img/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = 2500;
        $config['remove_space'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        $this->load->model('user_model');

        if($this->upload->do_upload(image))
        {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $this->user_model->insert_item($data);
        }
        else
        {
           $this->upload->display_errors();            
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$this->upload->do_upload('image');` instead of `$this->upload->do_upload();`

You have to pass your file input name  as parameter in `do_upload()` . If you are not passing the field name then by default it will take `userfile` . Thats why it is giving `You did not select a file to upload.` error

Answer (score 1):

Uploading file in codeigniter is much easier. Here i am writting both code for view file and controller file.

**View File**

```
<html>
<body>
<?php if(isset($error)){echo $error;} ?>
<?php if(isset($success)){echo $success;} ?>    
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload_controller/do_upload');?>
<input type='file' name='userfile' size='20' />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='upload' /> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller file**

For Enable file uploading we have to load one library its "upload"

**$this->load->library('upload');**

```
<?php 

class Upload_Controller extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
}

public function index(){
    $this->load->view('fileupload_view');
}

public function do_upload(){

if (!is_dir('/upload')) {
    mkdir('./upload',777,0);         
}

$config = array(
'upload_path' => "./uploads/",
'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
'overwrite' => TRUE,    
);

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if($this->upload->do_upload())
{
     $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();
     $data['success']= 'File Successfully Uploaded';
     $this->load->view('fileupload_view',$data);
}
else
{
     $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
     $this->load->view('fileupload_view', $error);
}
}
}
?>
```